# Best ways to avoid singularities in kernels when solving integral equations numerically

Tags: integral-equations

Take a Fredholm integral equation
$$
u(x) - \lambda \int_{-1}^{1} K(x,y)u(y) \, \mathrm{d} y = f(x)
$$
and discretize it via (say) Gaussian quadrature with nodes $\{x_j\}$ and weights $\{w_j\}$ to get
$$
u(x) - \lambda \sum_{j} w_j K(x,x_j)u(x_j) = f(x)
$$
It feels natural to use the same set of quadrature nodes over $f$ to get a linear system, so
$$
u(x_k) - \lambda \sum_{j} w_j K(x_k,x_j)u(x_j) = f(x_k)
$$
But if $K$ is singular, we have a big problem on out hands.

What are the normal methods of dealing with this?

Obviously we could use Gaussian quadrature nodes over $y$ and Chebyshev nodes over $x$, but that feels a little awkward; are there better ways?

Comment: Look into the locally corrected Nystrom scheme, which is designed specifically for this problem.

Comment: There is a substantial literature on quadrature in the context of the Boundary Element Method. You might want to look there.

Comment: To answer this question, we need to see your equation, not the Fredholm equation in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there are three major method families that are used (excluding locally corrected Nyström, as I am not an expert on this one):

1. **Treat the singularity**. [In this Q/A](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29111/calculation-of-the-efie-integral/29116#29116), I describe a canonical example in electromagnetics community with an EFIE integral, where for a singular integral, the singular part is treated analytically, while the rest is computed via regular quadratures. That Q/A includes a link [to a paper treating common integrals for integral-equation methods](https://doi.org/10.1109/TAP.1984.1143304), and there are some follow-ups.
2. **Use special quadrature rules** that are tailored to capture singularities. The paper by [J. Ma, V. Rokhlin, and S. Wandzura, "Generalized Gaussian quadrature rules for systems of arbitrary functions," *SIAM J. Num. Analysis*, vol. 33, no. 3, pp. 971–996, 1996](https://doi.org/10.1137/0733048) is one of the papers I often use, and it can serve as a great entry point in this topic.

Generally, using mixed quadratures can provide somewhat decent results in some cases within heavy adaptive integration (that's the third family); however, from my experience (and there might be references found) it is unable to provide stable high-accurate results or even compete over the aforementioned methods in terms of computational speed.